# Debugging Errors in Instagram Automation Script

Tags: instagram

I'm struggling to get my code to run after activating my environment. When I run the command `python main.py`, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\domin\OneDrive\Desktop\INSTAGRAM\myenv\Lib\site-packages\instaclient\client\driver.py", line 32, in start
> stdout=self.log_file,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> AttributeError: 'HiddenChromeService' object has no attribute 'log_file'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\domin\OneDrive\Desktop\INSTAGRAM\myenv\Lib\site-packages\instaclient\client\driver.py", line 32, in start
> stdout=self.log_file,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> AttributeError: 'HiddenChromeService' object has no attribute 'log_file'

This error occurred within the `driver.py` file of the instaclient package. It seems to be related to an attribute log_file that is missing in the HiddenChromeService object.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\domin\OneDrive\Desktop\INSTAGRAM\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import InstagramAPI
  File "C:\Users\domin\OneDrive\Desktop\INSTAGRAM\myenv\Lib\site-packages\InstagramAPI\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .InstagramAPI import *
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\domin\OneDrive\Desktop\INSTAGRAM\myenv\Lib\site-packages\requests_toolbelt\_compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I tried running the code using the command `python main.py`, and I was expecting it to execute without any errors.

```
# Import necessary modules
import InstagramAPI
import os

# Create an InstaPy session with your username and password
session = InstagramAPI(username='', password='')
session.login()

# Follow the followers of each given user
# The usernames can be either a list or a string
# The amount is for each account, in this case, 10 users will be followed
# If randomize is False it will pick in a top-down fashion
session.follow_user_followers(['friend1', 'friend2', 'friend3'], amount=10, randomize=False)

# Like posts based on hashtags
# The hashtags can be either a list or a string
# The amount is the number of posts to like for each hashtag
# The skip_top_posts parameter can be used to skip the top posts
session.like_by_tags(['#python', '#programming', '#coding'], amount=5, skip_top_posts=True)

# Leave comments on posts
# The comments can be either a list or a string
# The media parameter can be used to specify the type of posts to comment on
# Possible values are 'Photo', 'Video', 'Carousel', or 'Any'
session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=25)
session.set_comments(['Nice post!', 'Great content!', 'Awesome!'])
session.set_commenting_media('Photo')

# End the session
session.end()

# Import the instaclient library
from instaclient import InstaClient
from instaclient.errors.common import *

# Create an InstaClient object
client = InstaClient(driver_path='path/to/chromedriver.exe')

# Login to Instagram with your username and password
try:
    client.login(username='your_username', password='your_password')
except InvalidUserCredentials as e:
    print(e)
    exit()

# Define a list of users to follow or unfollow
users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

# Define a list of hashtags to like or comment on posts
hashtags = ['hashtag1', 'hashtag2', 'hashtag3']

# Define a list of comments to randomly choose from
comments = ['Nice post!', 'Awesome!', 'Great content!']

# Loop through the users list
for user in users:
    # Follow the user
    client.follow(user)

    # Unfollow the user after some time (in seconds)
    client.unfollow(user, delay=60)

# Loop through the hashtags list
for hashtag in hashtags:
    # Get the first 10 posts for the hashtag
    posts = client.get_posts_by_hashtag(hashtag, count=10)

    # Loop through the posts list
    for post in posts:
        # Like the post
        client.like(post)

        # Comment on the post with a random comment
        client.comment(post, comment=random.choice(comments))

# Logout from Instagram
client.logout()
```